# Работа с javafx (CVM)?

Tags: javafx

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется класс

```
public class View extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Text text=new Text("Привет");
        text.setLayoutY(100);
        text.setLayoutX(100);
        Group group=new Group(text);
        Scene scene=new Scene(group);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Заголовок");
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, каким образом можно вызвать объект этого класса из другого, который в свою очередь не является потомком `Application`?
Что то типа

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        View view=new View();
    }
}
```

а метод

`launch()` вызвать в конструкторе? Короче необходимо реализовать паттерн CVM

Comment: Вообще использование FX предполагает, что разметка пишется в .fxml файле, а управление отдается Контроллеру, ссылка на который уже разными способами может кочевать. Если вам нужно изменить например размер stage, но переведите его в разряд поля и сделайте геттер.

Comment: Из другого никак. В том же классе создайте `main` метод и напишите `launch()`. Java FX запускается при помощи рефлексии. не все просто так.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(View.class, args);
    }
}
```